# comprobar si existe un registro - en una tabla (EN LARAVEL)

Tags: laravel

En laravel he creado un sistema de encuestas

Tengo 3 tablas

```
Tabla 1 : Encuesta
Table 2 : Opciones_encuesta
Table 3 : opciones_usuarios
Table 4 : Usuarios
```

¿Cómo puedo saber si ya voté en una encuesta? ¿cómo accedo a él desde Laravel?

Mi relación es así:

```
Encuesta - opciones_encuesta
(tiene muchas opciones una encuesta)

Opciones_encuesta - Opciones_usuarios

(Una opción tiene muchos usuario que votaron por esa opcion)

Finalmente Usuarios
```

En la tabla, (opciones_usuarios)

Tengo estos campos:

```
-------------------
|Opciones_usuarios|
|-----------------|
|id               |
|opcion_id        |
|user_id          |
|-----------------|
```

¿Cómo compruebo si  ID_USER ya está en esta Tabla? Lo cual esa opción_id
 pertence a una encuesta.

¿cómo saber si ya voté en esa encuesta?

No sé si mis relaciones estén bien hechas. posiblemente tenga ahí el problema por eso no puedo mapear correctamente.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir los campos de todas las tablas y una descripción de que quieres hacer con esta base de datos?

Comment: Necesitamos más información, preferiblemente código para entender mejor la situación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas.

1. Relación directa en los modelos.
2. Consulta con query builder.
3. Consulta con eloquent

---

Caso uno

Modelo de encuestas.

```
<?php
namespace App //ruta donde este el modelo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Encuesta extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'Encuestas';
    protected $primarykey = 'EncuestaID';

}
```

Modelo de usuarios.

```
<?php
namespace App //ruta donde este el modelo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Usuario extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'Usuarios';
    protected $primarykey = 'UsuarioID';

}
```

Modelos pivote.
Modelo Opciones_encuesta

```
<?php
namespace App //ruta donde este el modelo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class OpcionEncuesta extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'OpcionEncuestas';
    protected $primarykey = 'OpcionEncuestaID';

    public function Encuesta()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Encuesta::class,'EncuestaID');
    }

}
```

Modelo opciones_usuarios

```
<?php
namespace App //ruta donde este el modelo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class OpcionUsuario extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'OpcionUsuarios';
    protected $primarykey = 'OpcionUsuarioID';

    public function Usuarios()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Usuarios::class,'UsuarioID');
    }

}
```

Estos modelos ahora tienen la relación de uno a muchos y puedes hacer lo siguiente con estos modelos.

```
use App\OpcionUsuario; 

$user = OpcionUsuario::Usuarios->where('UsuariosID' ,'>' , 0)->get();
```

Esto te regresara toda la información de la tabla opciones usuarios mas la toda la información de la tabla usuarios.

Igual pude funcionar al revés solo tienes que ver de que forma te conviene más.

---

Opción 2

Utilizando query builder

```
$app = \DB::query('SELECT Usuarios.UsuariosID, 
OpcionesUsuarios.OpcioneUsuarioID  
FROM Usuarios 
JOIN OpcionesUsuarios 
ON Usuarios.UsuariosID = OpcionesUsuarios.OpcioneUsuarioID 
WHERE Usuarios.UsuariosID > 1 ')->get();
```

Esto te traerá todos los campos que pidas en el select y que cumplan con el join.

---

Tercera opción.

Esta forma para mi es la mas fácil y al igual que con los modelos es mucho mas segura que usando query builder.

Eloquent

```
$app = Usuarios::where('UsuarioID', '>', 1)
->join('OpcionesUsuarios', 'OpcionUsuarioID', '=', 'UsuarioID')
->select('Usuarios.UsuarioID', 'OpcionesUsuarios.OpcionUsuarioID')
->get()
```

Espero te haya podido ayudar. Si te quedan dudas de como funciona o como lo puedes implementar en tu caso. Revisa la documentación de laravel.

Para query Builder y eloquent
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins
Para relaciones entre modelos.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships

Comment: obviamente si quieres solamente saber si existe la relación en lugar de get tienes que poner count() y en el where ajustarlo a la condición de quien quieres que exista.